# Catching exception and posting it back on the page

Tags: apex, exception

I am trying to catch an exception and have it send an email as well as post message back on the case record, when user hit save, so the user will see it as well.

what I am get is this "System.FinalException: ApexPages.addMessage can only be called from a Visualforce page:"

```
    try{
        integer = 10/0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
             // send email code

            // post message on page.
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));          
    }
```

Comment: Is this code part of a controller class?

Comment: this code is in a handler class, which is called by a trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error states the ApexPages methods are only valid when called from a controller associated with a visual force page currently being viewed/accessed.

If you are trying to add an error to a record use:

{THERECORD}.addError('There was an error');

NOTE: This will cause all DML to be rolled back OR DML for the current record to be rolled back depending on the settings of the calling method.

Emails should still be sent out but any DML will not. - Per sfdcfox this will NOT happen, emails will be rolled back.

Comment: Actually, any queued emails would also be rolled back, so they won't be sent. Only records that survive all the way to the end of the transaction will send emails.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean all DML will be rolled back.  It depends on how you do the DML since there are Database methods that allow for successful records to not be rolled back with it.

Comment: All this is happening in conjunction with a before trigger, so I am not using any DML statements.

Comment: @dphil - Hence my statement "depending on the settings of the calling method. Although I could make it clearer I was going for succinct

Comment: Eric solution worked, I'm seeing the error message, but @sfdcfox, is ight how the email doesn't get sent out, but it is getting rollback, but if I were to comment out the addError is when the email get sent out.

Comment: @dphil Even with allOrNone = false, any emails that were queued during the first run are rolled back when addError is used on at least one record; the entire transaction is re-run sans the failed elements, and only those emails will be sent instead.

Comment: @sfdcfox, so it seems like if I want catch to send an email, I can't use addError?

Comment: @MCHam Yes, addError causes a complete rollback of anything that the part of the transaction would have done, including future methods, queueable methods, batch methods, sending emails, and anything else you can think of that would otherwise survive the transaction.